# How to convert MS-WORD file into HTML in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing a project in which i have to to read a word document and perform some operation on file content. I have read the file successfully using 
Open XML, but that's not enough. It read the file but does not retain the format and indentation. So the solution i found is that first read the file and convert it into HTML. Another thing i want all file content in "String" because i have to perform further operation on file contents. 
So is there any way to read the MS-WORD file and convert into HTML and store in "string"?
  Here i am showing the code of reading MS-WORD file.

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult OpenFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                Rules R = new Rules();


                string FileText = "";

                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    R.name = filename;
                    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), filename);

                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    string filepath = path;
                    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true))
                    {
                        Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                        foreach (var paragraph in body.Elements<Paragraph>())
                        {

                                FileText += " <br> ";
                        }

                      }

                               R.Content += FileText;

                }

                return View(R);

            }
```

Comment: No one answer  the question but i got the solution.

Comment: Then you should share your solution. It may help others